# Generate a sequence of all permutation of some range of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, set

The following algorithm is given and we are supposed to write it out in java. However, when I try to understand line by line, it gets confusing, especially the part:

> A[k+1:N-1] = the values in S in ascending order

To my understand, the set only have 1 number at anytime. How can we replace `A[k+1:N-1]` when the set only has 1 number?

Let A be a sequence of integers `0` to `N-1` in ascending order (let's assume its an array of `int[N]`).

```
next_permutation(A):
    k = N-1
    S = { }
    while k >= 0:
        if S contains a value larger than A[k]:
            v = the smallest member of S that is larger than A[k]
            remove v from S
            insert A[k] in S
            A[k] = v
            A[k+1:N-1] = the values in S in ascending order.
            return true
        else:
            insert A[k] in S
            k -= 1
    return false
```

Comment: Why do you think S always contains one number?

Comment: Let's say N is 4.
It starts with nothing, so first loop will add 3 to the set. Second loop will replace 3 by 2, and then so on.

Comment: But what if the value in A[k] is smaller than A[k-1]? In this case, on the first iteration A[k] is added and k is set to k - 1. Then on the second iteration, S doesn't contain anything larger than A[k] (since k is different), so another element is added.

Comment: Oh seems like I've missed that post-permutation outcome. Let me work it out on paper again first!

Comment: @templatetypedef Any clue on how I can replace items in an array by values in a set in ascending order? e.g. A[k+1:N-1] = the values in S in ascending order. Should I use toArray()?

Comment: @templatetypedef A is a sequence of integers in ascending order. A[k] > A[k-1] for all k.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm shown is similar to the [Generation in lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order). You can read the article for further information.

> @templatetypedef Any clue on how I can replace items in an array by values in a set in ascending order? e.g. A[k+1:N-1] = the values in S in ascending order. Should I use toArray()?

This is not needed. You can try to keep the S array sorted all the time. Every time you want to insert a new number in the array, you insert it in such, so the array could stay sorted.
For example, if you have `S = [5 7 8]` so far and you want to insert `6`, you inserted between 5 and 7 - `S = [5 6 7 8]`. This way the replacement step is just copying the elements from S to A[k+1:N-1].